# How to configure GIRAPH 1.1.0 pom.xml for it to work with HADOOP 2.6.0 ? Installation ERROR

Tags: maven, hadoop, installation, pom.xml, giraph

Im trying to add GIRAPH 1.1.0 to HADOOP 2.6.0

I have to edit the pom.xml somehow in order to package GIRAPH correctly. I run the command `mvn -Phadoop_yarn -Dhadoop.version=2.6.0 package`

I edited the default pom.xml file in the line (1292) :

```
<id>hadoop_2</id>
          <modules>
            <module>giraph-accumulo</module>
            <module>giraph-hbase</module>
            <module>giraph-hcatalog</module>
            <module>giraph-hive</module>
            <module>giraph-gora</module>
            <module>giraph-rexster</module>
            <module>giraph-dist</module>
          </modules>
           <properties>
             <hadoop.version>2.6.0</hadoop.version>
```

but when I run the command it gives

```
[INFO] Apache Giraph Parent .............................. SUCCESS [4.183s]
[INFO] Apache Giraph Core ................................ FAILURE [5.364s]
[INFO] Apache Giraph Examples ............................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Giraph Distribution ........................ SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 9.911s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Mar 16 19:05:38 EET 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 55M/1020M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.0:compile (default-compile) on project giraph-core: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /usr/local/giraph/giraph/giraph-core/target/munged/main/org/apache/giraph/comm/netty/SaslNettyClient.java:[84,68] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   variable SASL_PROPS
[ERROR] location: class org.apache.hadoop.security.SaslRpcServer
[ERROR] /usr/local/giraph/giraph/giraph-core/target/munged/main/org/apache/giraph/comm/netty/SaslNettyServer.java:[105,62] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   variable SASL_PROPS
[ERROR] location: class org.apache.hadoop.security.SaslRpcServer
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :giraph-core
```

**my question is how should the pom.xml be modified for it to work with hadoop 2.6.0 ?**

Answer (score 2):

You are changing the hadoop version of the wrong profile. With the "-P" parameter, you are choosing it wrong.

For building giraph with hadoop_2 profile, you should use `-Phadoop_2` instead of `-Phadoop_yarn`, like this:

```
mvn -Phadoop_2 -Dhadoop.version=2.6.0 package
```

But, if you use Phadoop_2 profile, you won't be able to resolve the error that is related to `SASL_PROPS` variable, so, for avoiding it, you should use `-Phadoop_yarn` profile (but editing the hadoop version in the **hadoop_yarn** profile, instead).